# A line of VBA code in my macro works on it own, but fails when the entire macro runs

Tags: vba, excel

I tested each part of my code individually, before running the macro and all parts worked just fine.

The one that fails in my codes is:

```
SQL.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(SQL.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)).Copy
```

The error message is as follows:
Run-time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error

Here is my code up until the point of error. What could be going wrong?

```
Sub Prep()

Dim BO, HOC, Pol, Adv, Asg, Pay, SQL, Fml, Tbl As Worksheet
Dim c As Integer
Set BO = Sheets("BO")
Set HOC = Sheets("HOC")
Set Pol = Sheets("Policy")
Set Adv = Sheets("Advisor")
Set Asg = Sheets("Assignee")
Set Pay = Sheets("Payer")
Set SQL = Sheets("SQL")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

BO.Range("L:L").Insert
BO.Range("L2").Value = "=DATE(LEFT(K2,4),MID(K2,5,2),RIGHT(K2,2))"

With BO.Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(BO.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 12))
    .FillDown
    .Copy
End With

With BO.Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(BO.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 11))
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End With

BO.Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete

BO.Range("M:M").Insert
BO.Range("M2").Value = "=DATE(LEFT(L2,4),MID(L2,5,2),RIGHT(L2,2))"

With BO.Range(Cells(2, 13), Cells(BO.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 13))
    .FillDown
    .Copy
End With

With BO.Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(BO.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 12))
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End With

BO.Columns(13).EntireColumn.Delete

BO.Range("N:N").Insert
BO.Range("N2").Value = "=IFERROR(DATE(LEFT(M2,4),MID(M2,5,2),RIGHT(M2,2)),"""")"

With BO.Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(BO.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 14))
    .FillDown
    .Copy
End With

With BO.Range(Cells(2, 13), Cells(BO.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 13))
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End With

BO.Columns(14).EntireColumn.Delete

SQL.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
        Header:=xlYes

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Formulas"
Set Fml = Sheets("Formulas")

With Fml.Cells(1, 1)
    .Value = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)"
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End With

SQL.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(SQL.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)).Copy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to define the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) using two [Range.Cells properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) from other worksheets.

Define every reference within your definition explicitly.

```
SQL.Range(SQL.Cells(2, 2), SQL.Cells(SQL.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)).Copy
```

Or a more preferred method,

```
with SQL
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)).Copy
end with
```

Comment: Just made the change and that works! Thanks for the quick and lucid response! Now my mind will be at ease this weekend :)